# Absolute div not coming to the front because of overflow:hidden. Any alternative?

Tags: css, html, overflow

I have a problem to display the absolute positioned div and bring it to the front.

The relative div is small in height and the absolute one is big in height. And because I'm using floats inside the block divs, I've to use `overflow:hidden` to actually get the block div some height.

When I'm not using `overflow:hidden` and `floats` then the `z-index` applies just fine. But after applying `floats` and `overflow:hidden` the problem occurs.

[**Fiddle Link**](http://jsbin.com/sonokoki/10/edit?html,css,output)

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've to use overflow:hidden to actually get the block div some height.

you can use `clear:both` to give height for the parent of floating elements. you can use the `::after` pseudo element to clear the float as follows:

```
.block::after{
 content:"hi";
 display:block;
 clear:both;
}
```

[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sonokoki/14/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: No. I think that is for the following elements if you don't want them to get effected by previous floats. If yes, can you show a fiddle? I tried on mine. It messed up.

Comment: Why do you need to use `content`?

Comment: nothing, keep it empty, i put it for testing, check the updated link

Comment: I know it would work when we keep it empty. But why do we have to use `content:""` either?